# How to increase height of one component using FlexLayout, Angular 4, Material Design

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design, angular-flex-layout

I want to get a gap between the two rows, such as shown in [plunkr](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzyLqo) but I also want to have the middle cell in blue, on the top row, be a different height.

When I change the height of one cell it changes the entire row.  The one I was larger is `class="two"`

I have this html:

```
<md-card class="card-demo">
  <md-card-title>another example</md-card-title>
  <md-card-subtitle>some test work.
  </md-card-subtitle>
  <md-card-content>
    <div fxLayout="column" ng-app="demoApp" layout-fill>
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px" flex>
        <div class="one" fxFlex="70"> test1 </div>
        <div class="two" fxFlex="25"> test2 </div>
        <div class="three" fxFlex="25"> test2 </div>
      </div>
      <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap flex>
        <div class="four" fxFlex="150"> test1
          <p>one</p>
          <p>one</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

And this css:

```
.one {
    background-color: red;
}

.two {
    background-color: blue;
}

.three {
    background-color: green;
}
.four {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Vega - Basically we have three divs in the top. I want one to be larger but the other two to remain the same size.  I am trying to see if I can match the requirements from the UI designer.

Comment: There are four divs. in the plunker and in your code. In your code there are three colored 'zones'. Which one should be larger? could you name them for me?

Comment: @Vega - Thank you, I added more specificity.  Class="two" is the one I want larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add fxLayoutAlign to change default flex behaviour

```
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px" flex fxLayoutAlign="stretch flex-start">
    <div class="one" fxFlex="70"> test1 </div>
    <div class="two" fxFlex="25"> test2 </div>
    <div class="three" fxFlex="25"> test2 </div>
  </div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmborb?embed=1&file=app/app.module.ts

Comment: I went with the grid layout, but I like your approach also.